# implement nested abstract class with getter/setter

Tags: java, json, abstract-class, inner-classes

I have the following abstract class structure:

```
public abstract class A {
    ...
    private List<B> b;

    public List<B> getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(List<B> b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public static abstract class B {

    }
}
```

and implement it like this:

```
public class AA extends A {
    public static class BB extends B {
        ...
    }
```

When I now use the jackson to map Json on AA, I get an error, that it could not create an instance of A$B. I think this is, because the getter/setter in A still references on B and not on BB, which causes the error. Is there any way I can do it like that, without also putting the getter/setter in the subclass?

Comment: I think for inner class you should call that in Static way `A.B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add type capture to make sure b is always correctly typed like this:

```
public abstract class A<T extends A.B> {
    ...
    private List<T> b;

    public List<T> getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(List<T> b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public static abstract class B {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class AA extends A<AA.BB> {
    ...
    public static class BB extends B {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, and it worked for me as supposed. This was the solution i was looking for. Used `public class AA extends A<AA.bb>` and it didn't cause any compile errors.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options how to de-serialize. If you have no annotations, Jackson probably falls back to using a constructor of nearest superclass that has a public constructor with no parameters. After creating an empty object, it then sets the fields using reflections.

- Reflections WILL bypass any validations in constructor like `Objects.requireNotNull`.

A more refined way how to use Jackson is to use `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` in constructor, naming all the parameters.

- This enables you to force Jackson to use a constructor you made and validate the object.

I am quite unsure about this rather unusual structure. After all, you have an abstract class nested in an abstract class, I have seen a lot of things, but I haven't seen anything like this. Is there a good reason? Or is it not a problem to just move the inner class to a file of its own? (it is `public static` after all)

Comment: actually, since it's a public static class, it's quite like they're two different classes, it's just a matter of code positioning

Comment: Yes, it is quite likely that they are rather independent of each other. Moving it outside would remove at least some of the problems.

Comment: I didn't want to use annotations at first, because it works without and seemed easier to me.
There is no good reason not to move the inner class to a file of its own, just wanted to keep the Java class as close as possible to the JSON structure.

Comment: Also, are you sure you will never need to re-use `BB` in a different class? It is quite weird if e.g. `CC` returns `AA.BB`, and even worse if you have a `CC.BB` class that is a copy-pasted code.

Comment: Or, imagine JSON with multiple levels. Will you use `AA.BB.CC`? In the product I work on, we have rather simple JSON messages, but still, with some encapsulations, we got to four levels easily. Having a separate file for each class and good package structure makes it a lot easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an instance of `AA` you need an instance of the abstract class `B` and you define nowwhere, which instance to use. Just providing some implementation (`BB`) isn't enough.